# jquery mouseover area to get element

Tags: jquery, touch, swipe

So I have a piece of code that logs when a user swipes left and right with the mouse or touch on mobile.

What I need to do though is stop this on some elements within this area. so for example this code will log for any swipes in my mainContainer

```
var maxTime = 1000,
// allow movement if < 1000 ms (1 sec)
maxDistance = 50,
// swipe movement of 50 pixels triggers the swipe
target = jQuery('#mainContainer'),
startX = 0,
startTime = 0,
touch = "ontouchend" in document,
startEvent = (touch) ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown',
moveEvent = (touch) ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove',
endEvent = (touch) ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup';

target.bind(startEvent, function(e) {
    // prevent image drag (Firefox)
    // e.preventDefault();
    startTime = e.timeStamp;
    startX = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX;
}).bind(endEvent, function(e) {
    startTime = 0;
    startX = 0;
}).bind(moveEvent, function(e) {
    // e.preventDefault();
    var currentX = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX,
        currentDistance = (startX === 0) ? 0 : Math.abs(currentX - startX),
        // allow if movement < 1 sec
        currentTime = e.timeStamp;
    if (startTime !== 0 && currentTime - startTime < maxTime && currentDistance > maxDistance) {

        console.log(startEvent);
        if (currentX < startX) {
            // swipe left code here
           console.log("swipe left");
        }
        if (currentX > startX) {
            // swipe right code here
           console.log("swipe right");
        }
        startTime = 0;
        startX = 0;
    }
});
```

but within mainContainer I have a few sliders which when they are moved I do not want to get the log (trigger the condition).

All of my sliders have the class sliders.

I was thinking of having a if statement to say if where the mouse/touch starts is within this class the event doesn't happen. maybe this is the wrong approach?

If this is a good approach - how would i know if the mouse/touch was in this area?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if event.target has the class `.slider` :

```
target.bind(startEvent, function(e) {
     if ( !$(e.target).is('.slider') ) {
         startTime = e.timeStamp;startX = e.originalEvent.touches ?   
                         e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : 
                         e.pageX;
     }
}).bind(...
```